# Hiding notificationbar and title bar in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

In Styles.xml

```
<style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>  
  </style>
```

In Activity.cs

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true )]
```

I used below code to hide titlebar

```
Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle); //This will Hide the title Bar
             this.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen); //to hide
```

but nothing works.How to hide both title bar and notificationbar.Anr help appreciated.

Comment: please show your manifest file

Answer (score 3):

Add a Theme:

'Resources/values/NoTitleTheme.xml'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
<style name="Theme.NoTitle" parent="android:Theme">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
 </style>
</resources>
```

Use the Theme:

```
 [Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.NoTitle", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]

this.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);// this hides status bar of particular activity
```

Comment: title bar hides but how to hide notification bar(bar containing battery,wi-fi signal)

Comment: See updated answer and letme know if it helps. If it helped please accept the answer thanks.

Comment: Thanks!, Works for me.